# Bash script to change config using sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to change the value of malloc to say 1234m via a bash script but not seeing any changes.  I presume it is an issue with my regex, can anybody see what I've done inncorrectly?

String

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

Code

```
# get the memory allocation
echo "Enter the memory allocation"
read malloc

# update the default config
sed -ie 's/malloc,.*[0-9m]$/malloc,'$malloc'/gI' /etc/default/varnish
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `"` before the `$` in the sed pattern.

By the way, your pattern works, but in a different way than you probably intended: the character class `[0-9m]` matches just one character, `m` in this case. The number is being matched by `.*`. Better pattern might be `malloc,[0-9]\+m"$`.

Comment: This worked brilliantly, thanks! Can't believe I missed the m" at the end of the line!

Answer (score 1):

Try this sed command:

On Mac:

```
sed -E 's/malloc,[0-9]+m/malloc,'$malloc'/' /etc/default/varnish
```

or on Linux:

```
sed -r 's/malloc,[0-9]+m/malloc,'$malloc'/' /etc/default/varnish
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `sed` line worked for me, enclosing it in `"` rather than `'`:

```
 sed -ie "s/malloc,[0-9]\+m$/malloc,$malloc/gI" /etc/default/varnish
```